# Number of lines print in access.log every minute

Tags: logging, printing

I have a file (`access.log`) where i want to know how many times the word "example" is printed within the last minute.

Comment: Is this on windows, Linux... ? do you prefer bash, python... ? How do you want to do this?

Comment: Its in linux..bash,python both are prefered

Comment: How does the file content look like? Can you paste some sample extract and the expected output.